# Get value and null SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want (0 and null) values from column `installment`

```
where installment in (0, null)
```

but it is not working.

It is only returning `0` value.

Comment: `where (installment = 0 or installment is null)`

Comment: `NULL` is **not** a value (but rather the **absence** of a value). You cannot just compare it with regular `=` or `<>` comparison operators, or include in a list of values in a `IN (...)` clause. The **only** valid way is to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this instead:

```
where installment = 0 or installment is null
```

Or

```
where COALESCE(installment, 0) = 0
```

(`COALESCE` returns the first non-null value)